# Shell script calling ssh: how to interpret wildcard on remote server

Tags: shell, ssh, ksh

I work on a certain customer environment on a daily basis, comprised of 5 AIX servers, and sometimes I need to issue a same command on all 5 of them.

So I set up SSH key-based authentication between the servers, and whipped up a little ksh script that broadcasts the command to all of them:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        print "broadcast.ksh - broadcasts a command to the 5 XXXXXXXX environments and returns output for each"
        print "usage:                   ./broadcast.ksh command_to_issue"
        exit
fi

set -A CUST_HOSTS aaa bbb ccc ddd eee

for host in ${CUST_HOSTS[@]}; do

        echo "============ $host ================"

        if [[ `uname -n` = $host ]]; then
                $*
                continue
        fi

        ssh $host $*

done

echo "========================================="
echo "Finished"
```

Now, this works just fine, until I want to use a wildcard on the remote end, something like:

```
./broadcast.ksh ls -l java*
```

since the '*' is expanded on the *local* system as opposed to the remote.

Now, if using ssh remote commands, I can get around this by using single quotes:

```
ssh user@host ls -l java*    <-- will _not_ work as expected, since asterisk will be interpreted locally
ssh user@host 'ls -l java*'   <-- _will_ work as expected, since asterisk will be interpreted on the remote end
```

Now, I have tried to incorporate that into my script, and have tried to create a $command variable made up of the $* contents surrounded by single quotes, but have drowned in a sea of escaping backslashes and concatenation attempts in ksh, to no avail.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I'm not finding it so thought I would come out and ask.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Would double quotes work better? AFAIK they will preserve the wildcard but still expand the $.

Comment: Thanks, @Trengot, but they do not. That had been among the things I had tested, but I went ahead and re-tested now just in case. It still interprets the asterisk on the local system.

Comment: @James This will probably not answer your question, but could give you an idea other than creating your own script from scratch.  There's a tool called [**dsh**](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en), which is a wrapper to execute multiple shell commands into remote hosts.  Also, you may want to check [**this site**](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-run-commands/) for a nice example on how to use **parallel SSH**

Comment: @jim thanks for the suggestions. dsh sounds it does what I need... I wonder how it handles wildcards, lol. But I cannot install anything on this customer environments, that's why I need to fix my script, if at all possible. The IBM article looks very promising... I will definately read that, maybe the answer to my question is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 2):

As you found, passing an asterisk as an argument to your script doesn't work because the shell expands it before the arguments are processed. Try double-quoting `$*` and either escaping asterisks/semi-colons etc with backslashes in your script call, or single quoting the command.

```bash
for host in ${CUST_HOSTS[@]}; do
    echo "============ $host ================"
    if [[ `uname -n` = $host ]]; then
        "$*"
        continue
    fi
    ssh $host "$*"
done

$ ./broadcast.ksh ls -l java\*

$ ./broadcast.ksh 'ls -l java*; ls -l *log'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Josh, but neither one worked. The asterisk is still interpreted in the local system.

Comment: @James A workaround could be avoiding wildcards... I know, I know, not elegant at all :-p  
Something like `$ ./broadcast.ksh 'ls -l | grep ^java'` should work, I believe.

Comment: Yes @jim, it's not what I was hoping for when I decided to bring this to the SO community... but I have to admit some merit to the idea.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment but still too low on the totum, but Josh's single quote suggestion should work.

- I spun up a couple of vms each with 2 files in /tmp : /tmp/foo1 and /tmp/foo2
- then used a variation of your script

```bash
root@jdsdrop1:~# cat foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        print "broadcast.ksh - broadcasts a command to the 5 XXXXXXXX environments and returns output for each"
        print "usage:                   ./broadcast.ksh command_to_issue"
        exit
fi

set -A CUST_HOSTS jdsdropfed1 jdsdropfed2-2

for host in ${CUST_HOSTS[@]}; do

        echo "============ $host ================"

        if [[ `uname -n` = $host ]]; then
                $*
                continue
        fi

        ssh $host $*

done

echo "========================================="
echo "Finished"
root@jdsdrop1:~# ./foo.sh 'ls /tmp/foo*'
============ jdsdropfed1 ================
/tmp/foo1
/tmp/foo2
============ jdsdropfed2-2 ================
/tmp/foo1
/tmp/foo2
=========================================
Finished
root@jdsdrop1:~# ssh jdsdropfed1 "ls /tmp/foo*"
/tmp/foo1
/tmp/foo2
root@jdsdrop1:~# ssh jdsdropfed2-2. "ls /tmp/foo*"
/tmp/foo1
/tmp/foo2
```